# Programmatically Run prepareForSegue

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, segue

I want to run some code in the prepareForSegue. The problem is that I am changing views programmatically, so the prepareForSegue function is not being run. I also don't know how to run it because I can't give it an identifier.

prepareForSegue:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"hi");
}
```

Code I was trying to use to call the function manually:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"test" sender:self];
```

Code I'm using to change between views:

```
UIViewController *second = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"gameOverPage"];
[self presentViewController:second animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I guess if I can just set an identifier for the segue, my problem would be solved, but I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're not using `Storyboard`, you can't use the segue related methods.
Instead, just configure your controller before you present it.

```
UIViewController *second = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"gameOverPage"];
// configure your controller
second.propertyA = value;
[self presentViewController:second animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Identifier for a segue in Storyboard: Just click on the segue and choose the attribute inspector  (right side of Xcode), there you find a textfield "Identifier". Hier you can put your individual name of a identifier.